# How to mock vis js Network in angular test

Tags: angular, jasmine, vis.js, vis.js-network, angular-test

I'm writing the test for vis js graph implementation in angular. How can I mock/pass the **container** to the following in my test to mock out the network for the test?

```
this.network = new Network(container, graph, options);
```

I'm using lot of library functions from vis so I need mocked network so that I can continue using those.

I'm using angular 6 and vis version 4.21.0

Comment: container is derived from ViewChild (div in html) as follows:
`const container = this.networkDiv.nativeElement;`

Comment: `container` is just a DOM element, what's the problem with creating one?